# css alignment question

Tags: css, alignment, styling

I'm having trouble with getting unordered lists aligned how I want them to. Here's an image of what I'm looking to achieve. How can I get it to look like the version on the right?

[image]

I will have between 1 and 6 unordered lists depending on the page, so I need a generic solution. Here's a stripped down version of the css and html I'm using:

CSS:

```
    body { margin: 50px auto; width: 500px; }
    ul { 
        float:left;
        margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px; 
    }
    li { 
        background: #ddd;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 1px 0;
        padding: 5px
    }
    li.title { background: #333; color: #fff; }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li class="title">Title A</li>
        <li>1A</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Title B</li>
        <li>1B</li>
        <li>2B</li>
        <li>3B</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Title C</li>
        <li>1C</li>
        <li>2C</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a pure CSS technique which can handle this **generically**.

I've given up and used a jQuery plugin to do this in the past for something similar:

[**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/)

(There's also a raw JavaScript version: [Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/))

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with this solution. There's some other good suggestions here to that I didn't get a chance to try.

Answer (score 1):

`float:left` the `ul` you want in left, and `float:right` the ul you want at right.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xdyhy/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, and it appeared to work well at first, but if there was a mix of long and short lists, it would look a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the two left lists in a div and float that div left. Then float the remaining div right.

You will have to wrap them all in one containing div otherwise the rightmost div will fly off to the edge of the page.

Answer (score 0):

use **clear:both** in `ul`

```
ul { 
        float:left;
        margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px; 
        clear:both;
    }
```

see  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xdyhy/1/)