# Position floated elements directly under each other

Tags: css, positioning, css-float

I would like to display a row of tow divs next to each other while in the next row, the next div sits directly under the last one. Like this:

[image]

Because the layout has to be built into an CMS, I can't put Box 1,3 and 2,4 in a separat div. Is there a way to achieve this kind of behavior without extra wrapping elements? (Normal float behavior doesn't work, display inline/inline-block also doesn't do the trick.) Or is some JavaScript required to build a layout like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the different heights, this looks like the problem where I still haven't found a general purpose pure CSS technique to handle it properly, despite trying *really hard*.

I've posted this answer before:  [css alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015406/css-alignment-question/5015497#5015497)

> I've given up and used a jQuery plugin
> to do this in the past for something
> similar:
>
> [**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/)
>
> A picture is worth a thousand words:
>
> [image]

Comment: +1 seems like there is no pure css solution

Comment: Works great! Actually just the thing I was looking for! A pity I didn't the older Post, but thanks for posting it yet again.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the `nth-child(odd)` to `clear` the `float:left;`.

**css**

```
.box {height:100px;width:100px;float:left;}
.box:nth-child(odd) {clear:left;}
.green {background:green;}
.red{background:red;}
.blue {background:blue;}
.yellow {background:yellow;}
```

**html**

```
<div class="box green">BOX 1</div>
<div class="box red">BOX 2</div>
<div class="box blue">BOX 3</div>
<div class="box yellow">BOX 4</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YSP2S/

Keep in mind that this will not work for internet explorer. You can use [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and javascript to achieve the same for internet explorer also.

Comment: +1, works fine, so long as his heights *are not* different (like they are in his picture).

Comment: @thirtydot you are right. Hm, otherwise I don't think to exist any pure css solution, only a javascript like this you suggested.

Comment: The problem is that the heights of the boxes _are_ different, because they are post previews with text, and the text always differs in lenght, so looks like I'll have to use JavaScrip/jQuery as thirtydot suggested ... But still helpful, thanks! And I also haven't seen jsfiddle.net until now, looks great for sharing code examples!