# A Compressed Version of float: left

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have what seems like a simple problem, but i have yet to find a solution.  I have a series of divs which may vary in height, thought they will generally be the same width.  I would like a fluid layout that basically ends up generating a variable number of columns as the page is resized.  Perfect for float left.  The problem is that when the divs are different heights, there ends up being a lot of white space vertically between the elements.

Clearly, the simple solution is to write some javascript to do all of this for me.  But i would hate to have to resort to that if there's a css solution.

Here is a simple example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Simple Float Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .dv { border: solid 1px red; float: left; width: 300px; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="height: 40px;" class="dv"></div>
            <div style="height: 20px;" class="dv"></div>
            <div style="height: 60px;" class="dv"></div>
            <div style="height: 20px;" class="dv"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You'll see that when the page is very narrow, everything looks as you would expect.  All of the divs stack up.  If you expand the page to full size, yet again - everything looks fine.  But when there are 2 or 3 columns, look how much extra space there is.  I'd post an image, but my reputation does not yet permit me to do so.

Anyway, i experimented with various display and position settings, and i couldn't get it to really do what i want.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

-RP

Comment: Have you thought about making the heights percentage based instead of fixed values? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Robert - the heights actually aren't going to be so straightforward.  I won't be setting pixel heights at all.  Rather, the heights will vary based upon the contents.  Only the widths will be set.  So i can't do percentage heights either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after this type of look?

http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

If so, no, there is no easy way to handle that with pure CSS. You need a bit of JS as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no particularly good way to generically handle this with CSS.

Read this previous answer I wrote that goes over the various options, and shows that they don't work:

[CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234749/css-floating-divs-at-variable-heights/5234858#5234858)

You're stuck with JavaScript. Fortunately, the JavaScript you need has already been written in the form of a jQuery plugin:

[**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/)

I've suggested the same thing before:

- [Position floated elements directly under each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106578/position-floated-elements-directly-under-each-other/5106731#5106731)
- [css alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015406/css-alignment-question/5015497#5015497)

Comment: Great - although i was figuring this would require some javascript, i was not familiar with Masonry.  Despite a good hour of searching the web, i miraculously missed the simple combination of "float whitespace", which appears would have gotten me to the answer i needed...